# Array is Not assigned to Generic objects

Tags: typescript, angular5

here is my code

structure1

```
export class BankingChannePageData<T> {
    pagedata: T;
    revnum: number;
    pagetype: string;
}
```

structur2

```
import { BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter } from '../../models/banking-channel/banking-channel-common-revenue-center';
export class BankingChannelRevenueCenter<T> {
    common: BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter;
    specific: T;
}
```

Strurture 3

```
export class BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter {
    stateid: number;
    statename: string;
    districtid: number;
    districtname: string;
    subdistrictid: number;
    subdistrictname: string;
    centerid: number;
    centername: string;
    bankid: number;
}
```

here i have created one array

```
bcrevenuecenterarray: BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter[] = [];
```

and going to assign created array to generic objects 
like this

```
const bcrevenuecenterrequest = new BankingChannePageData<BankingChannelRevenueCenter<any>>();
    bcrevenuecenterrequest.pagedata = new BankingChannelRevenueCenter<any>();
    bcrevenuecenterrequest.pagedata.common = new BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter();
    bcrevenuecenterrequest.pagedata.common  = this.bcrevenuecenterarray;
```

**Problem**
Type 'BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter[]' is not assignable to type 'BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter'.
  Property 'stateid' is missing in type 'BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter[]'.

Comment: if `common:BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter` why do you try to assign an array to it ? `common:BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter[]` would declare an array of the type

Comment: yes I have  declare like that but no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared that field as an array of BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter objects, but then you tried to set that value as a single BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter.

BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter[] means "an array where each item in the array is an instance of  BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter".

If you want the field to only hold one item, then declare its type as 
BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter instead of BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter[] (remove the square brackets).

Comment: i want to hold an array of objects

Comment: Then your problem is that `bcrevenuecenterrequest pagedata.common` is either expecting an array or a single instance, and you're trying to set it to both, in back-to-back calls.     `bcrevenuecenterrequest.pagedata.common = new BankingChannelCommonRevenueCenter();` tries to set it to a single instance and 
    `bcrevenuecenterrequest.pagedata.common  = this.bcrevenuecenterarray;` tries to set it to an array

Comment: bcrevenuecenterarray: BankingChannelRevenueCenter<BankingChannelSpecificRevenueCenter>[] = [];